# Typescript compiler does not check validity of method' return type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is my problem:
I have a class which implements interface. Method greet should have return type `void` but in my implemented class it has `string` and compiler doesn't warn me. And IDE neither (I'm using PhpStorm).
Am I missing something or is this intentional?

```
interface Person {
    sex: string;
    greet() : void;
}

class Boy implements Person {
    sex: 'M';
    greet() {
        return this.sex;
    }
}
```

I'm using Typescript 2.0.10

Comment: The [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) doesn't do a warning or error either. But it *does* complain about it if you change `void` to `number` (saying that `greet` is incorrect because it returns  a string). So it's related to `void`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't complain because it doesn't really matter.
Your interface declares that the method returns `void`, if your implementation returns a value then no harm will happen.
Example:

```
let person: Person = new Boy();
person.greet();
```

As `person` is of type `Person` (and not `Boy`) then the `greet` method won't return a value, and indeed I'm not trying to use a return value.

On the other hand if it was the opposite:

```
interface Person {
    sex: string;
    greet(): string;
}

class Boy implements Person {
    sex: 'M';
    greet(): void {}
}
```

Then an error is thrown:

> Class 'Boy' incorrectly implements interface 'Person'.
>   Types of property 'greet' are incompatible.
>   Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => string'.
>   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.